# How to remove 13 year old metal loaded thermal paste

Tags: thermal-paste

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What chemical should I use for removing thermal paste?](https://superuser.com/questions/267463/what-chemical-should-i-use-for-removing-thermal-paste)

I've got an AMD-K6 CPU which has a duff fan, the thermal paste has gone solid and won't come off with alcohol or akasa heatsink cleaner (smells of citrus, like label remover). I'm assuming the residue contains copper as it polishes up nice and shiny but turns green when exposed to liquid. I've experimented, using a blade and crocus paper on the underside of the heatsink which worked quite well but I don't want to remove the CPU or subject it to the same rough handling (no spares).

Does anyone have a handy tip for removing this stuff from my CPU in-situ?

> I'm surprised this has been closed as
>   an "exact" duplicate as it refers to a
>   metal residue that has been left
>   behind after normal cleaning using TIM
>   remover.

Comment: ...and I stand by my recommendation in that thread for acetone, ESPECIALLY in this case.   You do probably want to run it a bit first so it's warmer and for goodness sake BE CAREFUL WITH THE STUFF.

Comment: This post is not a duplicate - it doesn't ask for chemicals nor is the answer only about chemicals. It is more general in scope.

Comment: I don't have accesss to pure acetone, so I used nail polish remover, smells like acetone but had no effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heating the paste by turning the processor on may soften it enough to be manipulated (carefully).

If not, see the procedure described here :
[How to Remove the TIM from a Stock AMD Heatsink and CPU](http://www.overclockers.com/how-to-remove-the-tim-from-a-stock-amd-heatsink-and-cpu/).

Specialized products are also a possibility, such as [ArctiClean Thermal Compound Cleaner](http://www.endpcnoise.com/cgi-bin/e/std/sku=arcticlean60)
(have never used it and cannot vouch for it).
Ask at your local computer store, or search "thermal compound cleaner" on your favorite Internet shop.

Comment: I'm not willing to risk the CPU running without a heatsink, it's circa 1997, IIRC AMD CPUs didn't have O/Heat protection then and tended to go pop.    I'll look for a different type of TIM remover to the Akasa one which didn't work.

Comment: You don't need to strongly heat the paste in order to soften it, turning on for a short-time may be enough. But of course you know best what is the status of this computer.

Comment: A hair dryer should be ok, they're designed not to scorch your skin. That's about the same temperature you're aiming for.

Comment: I have a heatshrink gun, not much call for a hair dryer (see avatar). I'll set it to low and have a go. Back tomorrow.

Comment: A 1 watt laser should heat it sufficiently  ;-> ...http://www.wickedlasers.com/lasers/Spyder_III_Pro_Arctic_Series-96-37.html

Comment: Heating the CPU made no difference, it really does behave like a metal deposit.

Comment: Try the other procedures, or get help from a repair-shop.

Comment: I mounted the CPU on a piece of wood with a depression routered into it and then screwed some metal tabs at the corners to hold it firmly in place. Very Heath Robinson but it allowed me to cut away the residue and clean the CPU. I've set your answer as the solution due to your last comment here, which gave me the idea of using a router to make a mount so I could work on the CPU safely. Thanks